# How to install an OSX application from source

Tags: install, xcode

I'm trying to install this application from source.

http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

It's not installed the same as the usual way in Linux. I got the source and built in in X-Code.

Now how do I install it into my system?

Answer (score 4):

Well...you could just download the compiled version. Then unzip it and move it to your applications folder.

But if you want to compile it yourself, that's fine, too. Once you built in in XCode, the built product will be in the `Development` folder (or the Deployment folder, depending on which build configuration you chose). Be sure to build the correct target. To build the Platyups.app, you want the `Platypus` target.

*Once you built the app, you can run it from right there*. Or move it to your applications folder.

Comment: Of course, in general, there's not always a compiled version available; consequently, this is a helpful answer. (Even ∃ compiled version of `platypus`).

Comment: New place is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/...`.